# How to convert array of objects to objects as required

Tags: javascript

I have two array of objects from which I am trying to loop and get a new object as per requirement.

**My 1st array**

This the header one

```
let billHeader = [
      {
        "billno": "A1",
        "companyid": "AAAA",
        "pending": "Y",
        "cancelled": "N",
        "salesman": "admin",
        "netamount": "225.0000",
        "billdate": "2020-01-16",
        "billtime": "11:15:29"
      },
      {
        "billno": "A2",
        "companyid": "AAAA",
        "pending": "Y",
        "cancelled": "N",
        "salesman": "admin",
        "netamount": "1500.0000",
        "billdate": "2020-01-16",
        "billtime": "11:18:29"
      }
    ]
```

**second one is buillInfo**

```
let billInfo =  [
  {
    "billno": "A1",
    "itemcode": "1002",
    "companyid": "AAAA",
    "unitprice": "125.0000",
    "itemname": "MANCHOW NV SOUP",
    "quantity": "1.0000",
    "totalamount": "125.0000",
    "categoryname": "SOUP"
  },
  {
    "billno": "A1",
    "itemcode": "1001",
    "companyid": "AAAA",
    "unitprice": "100.0000",
    "itemname": "MANCHOW V SOUP",
    "quantity": "1.0000",
    "totalamount": "100.0000",
    "categoryname": "SOUP"
  },
  {
    "billno": "A2",
    "itemcode": "1001",
    "companyid": "AAAA",
    "unitprice": "300.0000",
    "itemname": "MANCHOW V SOUP",
    "quantity": "2.0000",
    "totalamount": "600.0000",
    "categoryname": "SOUP"
  },
  {
    "billno": "A2",
    "itemcode": "1003",
    "companyid": "AAAA",
    "unitprice": "300.0000",
    "itemname": "Name Item",
    "quantity": "3.0000",
    "totalamount": "6300.0000",
    "categoryname": "SOUP"
  }
]
```

I want to loop through both of them and have an output exactly like this

```
 {
  "module": "outletbills",
  "status": "success",
  "billinfo": [
    {
      "billno": "A1",
      "companyid": "AAAA",
      "pending": "N",
      "cancelled": "N",
      "salesman": "admin",
      "netamount": "225.0000",
      "billdate": "2020-01-16",
      "billtime": "11:15:29",
      "billitems": [
        {
          "billno": "A1",
          "itemcode": "1001",
          "companyid": "AAAB",
          "unitprice": "100.0000",
          "itemname": "MANCHOW  V SOUP",
          "quantity": "1.0000",
          "totalamount": "100.0000",
          "categoryname": "SOUP"
        },
        {
          "billno": "A498",
          "itemcode": "1002",
          "companyid": "AAAB",
          "unitprice": "125.0000",
          "itemname": "MANCHOW NV SOUP",
          "quantity": "1.0000",
          "totalamount": "125.0000",
          "categoryname": "SOUP"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "billno": "A2",
      "companyid": "AAAA",
      "pending": "N",
      "cancelled": "N",
      "salesman": "admin",
      "netamount": "1500.0000",
      "billdate": "2020-01-16",
      "billtime": "11:16:41",
      "billitems": [
        {
          "billno": "A2",
          "itemcode": "1001",
          "companyid": "AAAB",
          "unitprice": "900.0000",
          "itemname": "MANCHOW  V SOUP",
          "quantity": "2.0000",
          "totalamount": "200.0000",
          "categoryname": "SOUP"
        },
        {
          "billno": "A2",
          "itemcode": "1002",
          "companyid": "AAAA",
          "unitprice": "125.0000",
          "itemname": "MANCHOW NV SOUP",
          "quantity": "1.0000",
          "totalamount": "600.0000",
          "unitcode": "NOS"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

How to start? I know several methods which will help me out like map, reduce, filter but don't know how to exactly do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bill items relate to a bill by its bill number - `billno`

```js
return {
    "module": "outletbills",
    "status": "success",
    "billinfo": billHeader.map(billHeaderEntry => {
        return {
            ...bill,
            billitems: billInfo.filter(billInfoEntry =>
                billHeaderEntry.billno === billInfoEntry.billno)
        }
    }),
}
```

And if you care not to modify some state...

```js
for (let billHeaderEntry of billHeader) {
    billHeader.billItems = billInfo.filter(billInfoEntry =>
        billHeaderEntry.billno === billInfoEntry.billno)
}

return billHeader
```

Comment: It is throwing bug can you please give a running example

Comment: Would you tell me which error, please ? Maybe object destructuring ?

Answer (score 1):

You could take a hash table for same groups and assign the items to the belonging group.

```js
var billHeader = [{ billno: "A1", companyid: "AAAA", pending: "Y", cancelled: "N", salesman: "admin", netamount: "225.0000", billdate: "2020-01-16", billtime: "11:15:29" }, { billno: "A2", companyid: "AAAA", pending: "Y", cancelled: "N", salesman: "admin", netamount: "1500.0000", billdate: "2020-01-16", billtime: "11:18:29" }],
    billInfo = [{ billno: "A1", itemcode: "1002", companyid: "AAAA", unitprice: "125.0000", itemname: "MANCHOW NV SOUP", quantity: "1.0000", totalamount: "125.0000", categoryname: "SOUP" }, { billno: "A1", itemcode: "1001", companyid: "AAAA", unitprice: "100.0000", itemname: "MANCHOW V SOUP", quantity: "1.0000", totalamount: "100.0000", categoryname: "SOUP" }, { billno: "A2", itemcode: "1001", companyid: "AAAA", unitprice: "300.0000", itemname: "MANCHOW V SOUP", quantity: "2.0000", totalamount: "600.0000", categoryname: "SOUP" }, { billno: "A2", itemcode: "1003", companyid: "AAAA", unitprice: "300.0000", itemname: "Name Item", quantity: "3.0000", totalamount: "6300.0000", categoryname: "SOUP" }],
    groups = {},
    result = billHeader.map(o => ({ ...o, billitems: groups[o.billno] = [] }));

billInfo.forEach(o => groups[o.billno].push(o));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: hey there is bug in your code it is giving me only one bill data i.e for `A1` it is not outputting `A2`

Comment: i get both. do you use the same data?

Comment: No data is dynamic, here I am having two bills A1 and A2, In future I can have A1,A2,A3 many more

Comment: @manishthakur, this is dynamic as well by taking `billno` as key for a group. please state what not work with your data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the naive approach to solve this. I think it's much readable and it'll provide you a better idea about what is going. You can easily loop through each arrays and add the new **billitems** to your **billHeader**. You can add your thought here to make it shorter.

```js
var output = {
  "module": "outletbills",
  "status": "success"
};
var billHeader = [{ billno: "A1", companyid: "AAAA", pending: "Y", cancelled: "N", salesman: "admin", netamount: "225.0000", billdate: "2020-01-16", billtime: "11:15:29" }, { billno: "A2", companyid: "AAAA", pending: "Y", cancelled: "N", salesman: "admin", netamount: "1500.0000", billdate: "2020-01-16", billtime: "11:18:29" }],
billInfo = [{ billno: "A1", itemcode: "1002", companyid: "AAAA", unitprice: "125.0000", itemname: "MANCHOW NV SOUP", quantity: "1.0000", totalamount: "125.0000", categoryname: "SOUP" }, { billno: "A1", itemcode: "1001", companyid: "AAAA", unitprice: "100.0000", itemname: "MANCHOW V SOUP", quantity: "1.0000", totalamount: "100.0000", categoryname: "SOUP" }, { billno: "A2", itemcode: "1001", companyid: "AAAA", unitprice: "300.0000", itemname: "MANCHOW V SOUP", quantity: "2.0000", totalamount: "600.0000", categoryname: "SOUP" }, { billno: "A2", itemcode: "1003", companyid: "AAAA", unitprice: "300.0000", itemname: "Name Item", quantity: "3.0000", totalamount: "6300.0000", categoryname: "SOUP" }],
groups = {},
result = billHeader.map(o => ({ ...o, billitems: groups[o.billno] = [] }));

billInfo.forEach(o => groups[o.billno].push(o));

output.billinfo = result;

console.log(output);
```

Comment: hey it is giving array of objects, I want just object please check my output I have suggested

Comment: @manishthakur i've returned the billinfo array, Please check now i've edited the code and now it's returning the object.